# Selectively suppressing legend in altair plot

Tags: python, altair

Stealing [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543503/add-legend-to-line-bars-to-altair-chart-without-using-size-color), is there any way to selectively suppress some of the elements in the color legend, e.g. to show the legend for the colors in the line but not the band?:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2,4,5,6], 'col2': [3, 4,7,4,4], 'col3': [1.5, 2.6,4.6,5.6,6.6], 'col4': [3.6, 4.6,7.6,4.6,4.4],'col5': [1.9, 2.9,4.9,5.9,6.9], 'col4': [3.9, 4.9,7.9,4.9,4.9]})


base = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    line="'line'",
    shade1="'shade1'",
    shade2="'shade2'",
)
scale = alt.Scale(domain=["line", "shade1", "shade2"], range=['red', 'lightblue', 'darkblue'])

line = base.mark_line(color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y=alt.Y('col2', title='Column 2'),
    color=alt.Color('line:N', scale=scale, title=''),
)

band_90 = base.mark_area(opacity=0.3, color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y='col3',
    y2='col4',
    color=alt.Color('shade1:N', scale=scale, title='')
)

alt.layer(
    line+band_90
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the legend of the band to `None` and then use an individual colorscale in the combined plot to make sure the line plot legend shows up:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2,4,5,6], 'col2': [3, 4,7,4,4], 'col3': [1.5, 2.6,4.6,5.6,6.6], 'col4': [3.6, 4.6,7.6,4.6,4.4],'col5': [1.9, 2.9,4.9,5.9,6.9], 'col4': [3.9, 4.9,7.9,4.9,4.9]})


base = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    line="'line'",
    shade1="'shade1'",
    shade2="'shade2'",
)
scale = alt.Scale(domain=["line", "shade1", "shade2"], range=['red', 'lightblue', 'darkblue'])

line = base.mark_line(color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y=alt.Y('col2', title='Column 2'),
    color=alt.Color('line:N', scale=scale, title=''),
)

band_90 = base.mark_area(opacity=0.3, color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y='col3',
    y2='col4',
    color=alt.Color('shade1:N', scale=scale, title='', legend=None)
)

(line+band_90).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

[image]

If you want to remove the legend entries for the band marker altogether you need to change scale to not include the "shade" groups in both plots:

```
base = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    line="'line'",
    shade1="'shade1'",
    shade2="'shade2'",
)

line = base.mark_line(color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y=alt.Y('col2', title='Column 2'),
    color=alt.Color('line:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=['red']), title=''),
)

band_90 = base.mark_area(opacity=0.3, color='purple').encode(
    x=alt.X('col1', title='Day'),
    y='col3',
    y2='col4',
    color=alt.Color('shade1:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=['lightblue']), title='', legend=None)
)

(line+band_90).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

[image]